# How to avoid docker overwriting nginx default.conf every restart nginx container

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

this is django web, there are 3 containers: nginx container, django container, mysql container. ngxin as proxy.
I want to nginx proxy to handle the static files for django web,so I want to change the nginx default.conf.
but docker overwrite the nginx default.conf every restart nginx container When I edit the nginx default.conf, so how to avoid overwriting?

below is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: N.9#n.9#
      MYSQL_DATABASE: log
      MYSQL_USER: log_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: log_pass
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"

  django-web:
    image: django-web
    restart: always
    container_name: django-web
    networks:
      - proxy
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: abc.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: abc.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: abc@gmail.com
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8000
    volumes:
      - "./django-web/:/app"
    links:
      - mysql

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/static:/app/static
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./nginx/dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - proxy
    restart: always

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-le
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always

volumes:
  certs:

networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

I try many times to change default.conf, restart nginx conainer doesn't work